# Milo - Run configuration settings

Tags: milo

I am interested create an Client Interface for a simulation software. So I have downloaded Milo and I went through the examples. I was able to build successfully when I executed `mvn clean package`. I would like to know how to set the run configuration for executing the Client `Example.java`.

Answer (score 0):

In the client-examples project. Look into the ClientExample.java source file. In this file 
update the method getEndpointUrl for server Endpoints. By default this method has a loop back Endpoints i.e :"opc.tcp://localhost:12686/milo".